Spring OAuth: JOSE header typ (type) string not allowed
I am using Java 17 and Spring boot 2.7.6. I am implementing Company SSO Integration with Spring Boot Application. SSO Authentication is successful and It redirect me to redirect URL with code and then Spring Security did Server to Server communication with my SSO with code to get ID_Token and Access_Token. But, at this stage, My Java application is complaining the following after while the tokens:
[invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: JOSE header typ (type) string not allowed

While checking Spring Security Logs. Found the following:
2024-06-07 04:42:35.473 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login/oauth2/code/?code=jyAQwknc-hq-vCdQGlQo5mHFI43YXrU
Pm5oIl-m4&state=D097uAEvCpoa31vGNNbWiTOml3pzl123fv_8Q11s_Bs%3D
2024-06-07 04:42:35.473 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2024-06-07 04:42:35.473 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://sso-dev.{COMPANY_FQDN}/as/token.oauth2
2024-06-07 04:42:35.473 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2024-06-07 04:42:35.474 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[jyAQwknc-hq-vCdQGlQo
5mHFI43YXrUPm5oIl-m4], redirect_uri=[https://{APPLICATION_FQDN}/login/oauth2/code/]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencode
d;charset=UTF-8"
2024-06-07 04:42:35.725 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2024-06-07 04:42:35.725 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2A
ccessTokenResponse] as "application/json;charset=utf-8"
2024-06-07 04:42:35.726 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oau
th2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
2024-06-07 04:42:35.726 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /login?error

In This stack overflow question I got clue that typ header parameter may be the issue.
I tried to change the typ parameter by applying filterChain:
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class JoseHeaderConfig implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (response.getHeader("typ") != null) {
             response.setHeader("typ", "JWE");
         }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

But, this FilterChain is not being applied to Server-Server communication which is happening internally in Spring Security.
How can I change the header incoming to make it compatible with Java Application. Assistant is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
